# SQL Advance Notification on data changes?

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlclr, smo

I need to notify my users when some data changes in some tables.

To do that I know I can define a trigger to insert some data in another table (tb_notification), and have a timer (in .NET app) to check that table and show some message to users.

That is one solution.

So is there another solution with **SQLCLR** or **SQL SMO** or even something else?

> I don't know too much about **SQLCLR** or **SQL SMO** and am looking for solutions to choose the best way to deal with this issue.

Comment: Where are your users (e.g. windows application, web browser, phone app, excel etc)

Answer (score 1):

Much of what will determine how best to notify users depends on what type(s) of notification(s) you are talking about. However, I don't think that **SMO** is going to do anything for you, with respect to notifications, as it is really for making general interaction with the meta-data much easier.

If you simply want to email users, you should call [sp_send_dbmail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) via a T-SQL Trigger. This system stored procedure runs asynchronously via Service Broker so it won't (at least shouldn't) hold up the DML statement.

If you need to call a Web Service, you *can* do that via a SQLCLR Trigger, or a T-SQL Trigger calling a SQLCLR function / stored procedure. The downside here is that there is much greater potential to have the DML statement hang while the web service call waits for a response, or even waits for the opportunity to make the request (depending on how you have max connections configured).

You also have the option of having a T-SQL trigger dump necessary info into a queue table, and then have a SQL Server Agent job run every minute or so to process records in that queue table. Just be sure to delete the records once they are "processed". This option is naturally asynchronous, hence making a Web Service call via SQLCLR is much less risky. Or this approach can be used in combination with `sp_send_dbmail` so that you have "instant" email notification *plus* the ability to do something more generic with that data in the queue table, such as send it to a common audit database so that a UI can be added to have a more "global" look into what is changing that many people can look at via your app.